# How to allow anyone to spend tokens from Wallet using erc721?

Tags: solidity

I want to approve all addresses to spend tokens from my wallet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think allows all people use token from your wallet is a good idea. It would be great if you could elaborate the your idea and people can give you help.

But if you really need it, this can achieve by create a contract with a public function like

```
address yourWalletAddress = 0x....;
uint256 claimAmount = 0.5 ether;
function claimToken() public {
    TokenInterface = TokenInterface(yourWalletAddress);
    TokenInterface.transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, claimAmount);
}
```

Comment: okay then how is that if we approve the contract to send tokens on our behalf ?

Comment: from your wallet, call the approve function of the token. Specify the address of the new contract you've just created.

Comment: i call the approve function from the owner account to approve the contract 

  function _approve(uint256 tokenId) internal virtual  {
        
        emit Approval(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);
    }

Comment: after that i switch the account and run the function


function winNft (uint winningNft ) internal  returns(bool){

    for(uint i=0; i < winningNft; i++){
        uint256 winningId =  block.timestamp % ((tokens.length-1) - min + 1) + min;
_transferFrom(address(masterWallet),msg.sender,tokens[winningId]);
    }
    return true;
    }